# Adjust font size on td class="hidden-phone"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a column whose font size I want to shrink but I can't get the setting to take affect.  Here's the original code:

```
<td class="hidden-phone"><%= thing_to_shrink %></td>
```

I've tried:

```
<td class="hidden-phone" style="font-size:small;"><%= thing_to_shrink %></td>
```

and

```
<span style="font-size:small;"><td class="hidden-phone"><%= thing_to_shrink %></td></span>
```

Anybody have ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: It will not work if you use `<td>` outside `<table>` :) It works like it should do http://jsfiddle.net/Pex8S/

Comment: I do have it contained in a table.  I only want to shrink this columns entries, not everything that is "hidden-phone".

Comment: `<span style="font-size: small;"><%= thing_to_shrink %></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `thing_to_shrink` is returning, if it's a string it should work and will take font size say `12px` of `hidden-phone` class

```
<td class="hidden-phone">SOME STRING</td>
```

But it is generating HTML something like following

```
<td class="hidden-phone">
  <span style="font-size:20px;"> SOME STRING</span>
</td>
```

then it will take the font size 20px instead of 12px